How to add @ts-ignore solution to Quick Fixes?
I would like to add an option to VSCode's Quick Fix that adds // @ts-ignore above a warning to make it go away. Currently, I only get the below option for resolving noUnusedLocals warnings:

Is there a way to force Quick Fix to show // @ts-ignore as a solution?
I've looked around online, but found little to no formal documentation on how Quick Fix works.
STR sample:
// Need to get @ts-ignore here.
function someFn (){
    //   ^^^^^^ From ctrl+. "Quick Fix" menu option here.
}

const makeThisModule = 1;
export default makeThisModule;
// don't export { someFn };


And does (manually adding) //@ts-ignore above that function declaration really make the warning go away? I guess the "ignore" makes sense only for real TS errors (usually around types), not linter "suggestions" about unused code. I guess the unused function will remain unused with or without the "ignore" (?) Do you know where is the suggestion coming from exactly? If from ESLint, then better solution could be setting up ESLint to be more lenient about unused functions.

The @ts-ignore is a compiler directive for the Typescript compiler. If the error is coming from eslint, which is a completely different tool, then you would need to use an eslint-ignore directive instead.

This question is similar to: Turning off eslint rule for a specific line. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Does the Problems view undicate the source (eslint or tsxxxx) for the that particular warning?

@myf Yes, adding it makes the warning go away. The error is not from eslint; apologies for the confusion. I've removed mentions to eslint in the original question.

@JaredSmith sorry - not related to eslint. I've removed mentions to eslint from the question. The question you linked does not solve my problem; I want to be able to do this from the VSCode Quick Fix menu, I don't want to have to type it in manually.

@Mark The source is ts(6133). I've removed mentions of eslint from the original question.

Ok, so I'm not sure that you can do that, because the obvious solution to an unused variable is to delete the variable, and that's going to be what the plugin is going to prompt you to do. It typically will only recommend adding a compiler directive like that if it doesn't know a better solution. Frankly if you really, really need to keep it around for some reason you could just comment it out, but I'd get rid of it if it were me and fish it out of the git history if I needed it (assuming it's been committed at some point).

And to clarify, changing linter rules will not solve my problem. I want to be able to quickly ignore warnings while debugging, only on warnings that I specifically intend to ignore at that moment (I don't want to ignore warnings on an entire file at once, for example)

@fart yeah, we get it, your edits to the question are most cogent +1. I still don't think you're going to be able to get what you're after here, but I could be wrong. If it were me per my earlier comment I'd delete it or Cmd+L followed by Cmd+/ to comment the line.

@JaredSmith This is mostly an issue with function declarations, which can be up to several dozen lines I'd have to comment out. I can always just add an AHK hotkey to quickly paste in the ignore line, but I was really hoping for a native solution in VS Code :)

@fart for functions you could always just export them, that would remove the error. You could also comment out the function by doing Ctrl+Shift+Right with the cursor in the function body followed by Cmd+/. I guess I still don't get why you need to be able to compile with unused functions, but it's your code.

@fart Could you make a small repro (at codesandbox.io / GtHub Codespace / StackBlitz / anything using VSC) with your workspace config showing the issue? Or show us your config? Currently I am unable to even make my VSCode nag about unused functions.

Made VSC suggest the "remove unused" quick fix (Added STR to your question) so can confirm there is no "add ts-ignore" there for me either for TS. Yet the presence of //@ts-ignore makes no difference for me there. NB: switching syntax of the very same file to JavaScript makes VSC offer "ignore" and even "disable checking for this file" in quick fix options.

@myf Ah, you probably need "noUnusedLocals": true, in your tsconfig.json compileroptions to see this warning.

I've created a VSCode extension to do this:

